# html page chinese character is not displaying correctly

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jsp, utf

I have a Given Hex value in ASCII `3f:3f` value of a Chinese character

> 没有

[image]

When i cover it back to string, it fails to display the chinese character

[image]

Not Sure where to change the Encoding any Help will be appreciated.

This is logic of Sending string and displaying it back in JSP page

```
 $('#form').submit(function (event)
                    {
                    //  
                  $('#outputtext1').html('<img height="20" width="20"  src="images/712.GIF"> loading...');
                     event.preventDefault();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "StringFunctionality", //this is my servlet
                           data: $("#form").serialize(),
                            success: function(msg){    
                                  $('#outputtext1').empty();
                                        $('#outputtext').empty();
                                     $('#outputtext').append(msg);

                            }
                        }); 
                    });
        });
```

And the result s captured and Displayed Via HTML

```
<div class="form-group row">
            <label for="outputtext"  class="font-weight-bold col-sm-2 col-form-label">Output</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea name="outputtext" class="form-control" id="outputtext" cols="2" rows="3" ></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: is it taking back from db??

Comment: nope, just converting the given Hex String to String

Comment: `3f` is `?`. The problem is your string to hex conversion is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are trying to convert Chinese characters to ASCII. The problem is that [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) only covers some of the Latin characters.

As said by Musa in the comments 3f is the ASCII hexadecimal value for the question mark.

When you try to convert a string from one encoding to another that only support a subset of characters (e.g. from UTF-8 to ASCII) it will replace the characters that cannot be encoded with a default one (or drop them). In your situation it replace the Chinese character with the question mark.

So the current behavior is normal. You might want to do some test before performing the conversion to make sure that the target encoding is able to encode the character provided.